# jQuery selector not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple html

```
<div id="dCA" style="width: 200px; margin-right: 20px; float: left;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="AL" onclick="cs('1', this);">Alberta </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="BC" onclick="cs('2', this)">British Columbia</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="M" onclick="cs('3', this)">Manitoba</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="NB" onclick="cs('4', this)">New Brunswick</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="NF" onclick="cs('5', this)">Newfoundland</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="NS" onclick="cs('6', this)">Nova Scotia</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="On" onclick="cs('7', this)">Ontario </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="PEI" onclick="cs('8', this)">Prince Edward Is </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="Q" onclick="cs('9', this)">Quebec </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="SK" onclick="cs('10', this)">Saskatchewan </a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I am trying to access the "a" but it's giving me undefined.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any help will be appreciated

I am trying to access like this,

```
alert($("#dCA").find("ul>li>a:contains('" + "Alberta"+ "')").attr("id"));
```

Comment: I get "AL" http://jsfiddle.net/qtv44962/

Comment: What is it that you want exactly? The code provided by you gives the ID as required.

Comment: are you running your code in $(document).ready() ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works and gives "AL", however there is no need of `" + "Alberta"+ "`. This also works

```
alert($("#dCA").find("ul>li>a:contains('Alberta')").attr("id"));
```

**Fiddle:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/9dobfj8h/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert($("#dCA").find("ul>li>a:contains('Alberta')").attr("id"));

})
```

or add the script after the html.